# Number of NOP Instructions per second

Tags: c, assembly

I'm writing a program to determine how many NOPs per second can be run, but the number I'm getting seems extremely small.

```
int main()
{
    struct timeval tvStart, tvDiff, tvEnd;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned long numberOfRuns = 0xffffffff;

    gettimeofday(&tvStart, NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < (unsigned int) 0xffffffff; i++)
    {
        hundred(); /*Simple assembly loop that runs 100 times and returns */
    }   
    gettimeofday(&tvEnd, NULL);

    timeval_subtract(&tvDiff, &tvEnd, &tvStart);

    /* Get difference in time in microseconds */
    unsigned long nopTime = (tvDiff.tv_sec * 1000000L) + tvDiff.tv_usec;
    printf("NOP Seconds: %lu\n", nopTime);


    gettimeofday(&tvStart, NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < (unsigned int) 0xffffffff; i++)
    {
        none(); /* Assembly function that just returns */
    }
    gettimeofday(&tvEnd, NULL);

    timeval_subtract(&tvDiff, &tvEnd, &tvStart);

    /* Get difference in time in microseconds */
    unsigned long retTime = (tvDiff.tv_sec * 1000000L) + tvDiff.tv_usec;
    printf("RET Seconds: %lu\n", retTime);

    unsigned long avgTime = nopTime - retTime;

    /* Takes number of NOP runs and divides it by the time taken
    and multiplies by 1,000,000 to convert to seconds */
    printf("%lu\n", ((numberOfRuns * 100) / avgTime) * 1000000);
}
```

The first thing I do is run an assembly loop that consists of 100 NOP instructions `0xffffffff` time and store the time it took in `nopTime`. Then, I do the same, but instead call an assembly function that just returns.

I believe I should be getting at least 1,000,000,000 NOP instructions per second, if not more, but I'm not even close. Here's the output of my last run:

```
NOP Seconds: 251077086
RET Seconds: 10450449
/* Calculated number of NOPs per second */
17000000
```

I'm not quite used to using larger data types, so are things being truncated and I'm not realizing it? Should I be making use of doubles? It seems that when I mess around with the data types, I get different numbers, but they are also fairly small numbers.

Is my logic just wrong?

Comment: How did you come up wth your estimate of NOPs per second?

Comment: It was more of a lower bound, but I thought most processors nowadays can do thousands of MIPS.

Comment: Yes, yes...establishing timing is extremely difficult with all those function calls, inacurate timers, OS interrupts etc. Better refer to the spec manual of the CPU.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yeah, you're definitely right. Just wanted to try and code something to get a rough estimate for practice.

Comment: Well you did introduce two variable reads and one variable write per iteration in your timings.

Comment: @sturcotte06 That's a good point, but would it really affect instructions per second by that much?

Comment: Well, you have 3 operations to execute on the processor for each loop iteration, + 1 for the NOP operation (considering gcc does not optimize the call out). A NOP operation is simply an operation to execute on the cpu that takes a single cycle, like a read or a write. It's probably a bit faster than other operations, since it does nothing, but the difference should be negligible.

Comment: You might have better luck performing some predetermined number of NOPs in sequence (i.e. an unrolled loop, to avoid the overhead of a JMP call), and extrapolate from there with some simple division to determine how many could have been done in a second.

Comment: You're mostly timing how long it takes to execute a loop 4 billion times!  The instructions that increment and test the counter and branch conditionally certainly aren't noops! A more useful thing to do would be to execute one loop with 1000 noops in the body and another the same number of times with 2000 noops and look at the difference. That _might_ give you a better indication of actual performance. 10000 and 20000 might be even better.

Comment: http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp (I didn't explore it myself, but I bet there's lot to learn from this one)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get NOP's in C but it may be possible using inline assembly. But even if you can write the NOPs inside the for loop with inline assembly, the actual loops generate arithmetic and branch instructions.

And if you compile without optimizations, you will even get memory loads and stores and those are slower.

Other than that, the theoretical speed of NOPs and nothing but NOP instructions on a pipelined CPU should be the same as the CPU frequency.

For practical purposes, if you really want to measure, you should write a loop in assembly that uses just registers, and inside the loop you have NOP instructions as much as they fit in a single instruction-cache block or maybe few blocks.

If you do this in C, compile with optimizations `gcc -O3` so the for loop counter is only registers, and also make sure that the NOPs don't get optimized away. Look at the output assembly with `gcc -S`.